# Click on show more button; selenium scrape with python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to scrape a website with show more button; and I'm not able to click on it.
The website is: https://www.wtatennis.com/rankings/singles

And my code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
browser.get('https://www.wtatennis.com/rankings/singles')

action = ActionChains(browser)
showmore = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//button[contains(@class, 'btn widget-footer__more-button rankings__show-more js-show-more-button')]")
action.move_to_element(showmore).perform()
showmore.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Has anyone any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Hi - it’s scrape not scrap. To scrap means to throw away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't use './/' in your locator when you are starting the search from root, as there is no current element your locator won't find any element. Also you can use any attribute to find elements uniquely. see below code:**

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser.get('https://www.wtatennis.com/rankings/singles')


WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
    '//*[@data-text="Accept Cookies"]'))).click()


WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
    '//*[@data-text = "Show More"]'))).click()
```

**use webdriver wait and data attributes**

**tu use wait import:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

To wait till all elements are loaded you have to make sure last element is not changing , if its changing keep scrolling .

```
browser.get('https://www.wtatennis.com/rankings/singles')


WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                             '//*[@data-text="Accept Cookies"]'))).click()

value = "start"
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                             '//*[@data-text = "Show More"]'))).click()


while(browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//tr[@class='rankings__row'])[last()]").text != value):
    elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        '(//*[contains(text(),"Loading")])[2]')
    value = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        "(//tr[@class='rankings__row'])[last()]").text

    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", elem)

    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
                                                                          "//tr[@class='rankings__row']")))

    try:
       WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until_not(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH,
                                                                           "(//tr[@class='rankings__row'])[last()]"), value))
    except:
        None
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This is working, but clicking only once. Is it possible to click until there is no button anymore?

Comment: @owce added the answer see , the updated part please accept the asnwer and upvote by ckicking the tick sign if it helped

Comment: Thank you @PDHide, this is perfect!